# running texshop?

Tags: mactex, texshop

I just downlodaded MacTeX from website below for my Mac Osx 10.6.8:

http://www.tug.org/mactex/2009/

I am trying to run some older `.tex` files and they won't run, the message is:

> Syntax error

Do you know what is happening?

Here is copy of a simple `.tex` file I am trying to run:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{center} {\bf  Abstract} \end{center}

In the present work, we define brain to brain communication as the associated information transfer in non-local wave function collapse.  We analyze non-linear Schrodinger type equations of Benney-Roskes and Davey-Stewartson in non-linear optical systems, and ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: This is probably not related, but why did you choose an old version of you TeX distribution? [MacTeX 2012](http://www.tug.org/mactex/) is said to work with > Mac OS 10.5. (Also not related but worth a read: [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516))

Comment: Well, what happened was I lost my hard drive, got a new one and then it came with 10.6.8 version.  However,  before this new version,  I had Latex running just fine. Today,  I downloaded MacTeX.mpkg.zip from:

Comment: I downloaded MacTeX.mpkg.zip from:   http://www.tug.org/mactex/2009/   And when I open texshop and run a file previously existing in my documents,  I get an error :  'Can't find required tool,  /usr/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. Perhaps TeXLive was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to the TeXShop web site and follow the instructions to (re)install TeXLive. Another possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the fink teTeX distribution'.  Help!!  Thank you!

Comment: I must confess that I'm puzzled by the fact that you chose to install an obsolete version of MacTeX. As another commentator has already pointed out, the current version of MacTeX is **2012**. It should run just fine on MacOSX 10.6.x.

Comment: Download and install MacTeX 2012, the current one that you find at http://tug.org/mactex and all should go well.

Comment: Without something more to go on (at least a partial log) we can't hope to answer this: thus 'too localized'.